# BusyIndicator animation stops with delayed operation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, busyindicator

I'm trying to show a busy indicator on fetching data from another source.

Workflow

1. Busy indicator starts on process starting
2. Fetching data.
3. Stop busy indicator.

Sample code

**Xaml**

```
 <busyIndicator:BusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" IsBusy="False" >
        <Grid>
            <Button x:Name="showindicator" Height="100" Width="200" Content="ShowIndicator" Grid.Row="1" Click="Showindicator_Click"/>
        </Grid>
    </busyIndicator:BusyIndicator>
```

C#

```
private async void Showindicator_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
            await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                // In my original code, fetching data here
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }));
            BusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
        }
```

Busy indicator doesn't start while dispatcher loop is in progress, the indicator starts only after the loop. In above case indicator not showing, but if IsBusy flag not set to false indicator starts after the loop.

I don't know Am I doing anything wrong or the logic not correct? Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be performing your heavy operation on the GUI thread - this is because `Dispatches.BeginInvoke` dispatches the action to the GUI thread.

It can be easier:

```
BusyIndicator.IsBusy = true;
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    // this is now running in the background

    // In my original code, fetching data here
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        Thread.Sleep(1000); 

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
        {  
             // do UI stuff here
        });
    }
});

BusyIndicator.IsBusy = false;
```

Comment: Yes above code working fine with busy indicator, but while processing the data I'm facing following exception. 

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.'

Comment: @KarthikRajaAKR: Then you are probably trying to access the busy indicator or some other control from the background thread. This is not allowed.

Comment: Probably, you're trying to change something on the GUI within your "fetching data" code. I've  updated the example

Comment: @arconaut thank you for your response. In my project, I'm creating UI using the data fetched using thread function. Here data is used as DataContext for UI later in my project. So I can't do UI related changes within the thread. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You can do UI related changes by putting them in the action sent to `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`. It could look like this: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => UpdateUI(recentData))` or see similar code in my answer above ;)